# Can i use ingress controllers to configure existing Load Balancer provisioned for Kubernetes Bare Metal

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, bare-metal-server

We have seen on cloud that installing an ingress controller, automatically provisions a LoadBalancer and ingress rules configure Load Balancer itself.

We have used [k8s-hard-way](https://github.com/ddometita/mmumshad-kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/358fd23331f139031e87a69271e3820873b27d99/docs/08-bootstrapping-kubernetes-controllers.md#the-kubernetes-frontend-load-balancer) to establish a k8s cluster on bare metal

Here on a bare Metal K8s, we have already provisioned a LoadBalancer as described in [this section](https://github.com/ddometita/mmumshad-kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/358fd23331f139031e87a69271e3820873b27d99/docs/08-bootstrapping-kubernetes-controllers.md#the-kubernetes-frontend-load-balancer)

Can we use Ingress controllers like Kong / HAProxy/ Nginx to configure this existing Load Balancer via Ingress rules?
If Not, what should be the way?

Answer (score 0):

So generally when **Nginx ingress** controller or any other controller like **Kong** got installed to **K8s** it creates the service type **LoadBalancer**.

You can create or modify the **service** that got created by default and map your **LoadBalancer** IP to the **service**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
  ...
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 192.168.0.01
```

Now your controller service is pointing to the **LB IP** and your service is exposed to the internet.

Map **LB IP** to **hostname** in **DNS** and you are good to use it.

Comment: do we need not to configure the LB frontend backend rules?

Comment: you can use the ingress right with rules and that will be managed by the ingress controller.

Comment: does'nt it happen only on cloud that ingress configures the auto provisioned Load Balancer? As far as i have understood, on bare metal K8s we have to manage everything ourself, like creating ingress rule and then configure HAPRoxy LoadBalancer backend and frontend rules  ourself ? Let me know if i am wrong

Comment: yes right you are the process will be the same once you have external LB IP attached to the ingress controller you can create rule and other setup.

Comment: i just assigned   loadBalancerIP: 192.168.2.148 to my LoadBalancer Service that got created when i installed Ingress controller but External IP is still Pending. Why is that?



service/haproxy-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.96.201.135   <pending>     80:31538/TCP,443:31358/TCP   4m31s

Comment: yes ideally should be showing there IP assigned to `haproxy-ingress` service instead of pending.